# Visually Compare employee performance through excel graph?

Tags: excel, charts, compare

I'm trying to make a line graph to visually compare employee performance.  I know this can't be as hard as it seems but I can't get my graph to turn out right.  Please help?  I have two employees, Rick and Don.  They work from 6 am to 3 pm.  Throughout the day they should complete as many tasks as possible.  Each task has a tonnage unique to that task.  One task may be 1 ton and another may be 22t.  So if they get many 1 ton tasks, that is as good as 1 22 ton task.  They may be more efficient at certain times of the day.  Attached is the image of the basic information.  I've tried to do the line charts but it is charting only two sets of data and I can't compare it well.

I'd like the average time and tons to be the x / y axis and their performance to plot on points on the chart (each employee in different colors).  Is that specific enough?  I can send a picture if needed, I don't have enough reputation right now.

```
EmployeeTime    CompletedTons   EmployeeTime    CompletedTons   AvgTimes      AvgTons
Rick    7:00    10              Don     8:41    0.1             6:00          0
Rick    7:37    0.28            Don     8:57    0.13            7:00          2
Rick    8:25    2.5             Don     9:28    21.55           8:00          4
Rick    8:54    1.25            Don     10:11   0.025           9:00          6
Rick    9:13    1.13            Don     12:50   0.13            10:00         8
Rick    10:20   5               Don     13:51   0.1             11:00         10
Rick    10:31   2.5             Don     14:35   0.18            12:00         12
Rick    11:08   6.18                                            13:00         14
Rick    12:34   10                                              14:00         16
Rick    13:12   1                                               15:00         18
Rick    13:50   1.5                                                           20
                                                                              22
                                                                              24
```

Comment: couldn't you just sum the tons, and take last time - first time, with can be converted to something like tons/hour - under **Rick**, put `=SUM(C:C)/((MAX(B:B)-MIN(B:B))*24)` and under **Don**, put `=SUM(F:F)/((MAX(E:E)-MIN(E:E))*24)` and that will give you a comparison

Comment: But I also want to measure performance throughout the today.  So Employee Don was only very productive at one point during the day where Employee Rick was consistently productive throughout the day.